# ajax Json return type not comming in success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Company/validateForm",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'txtCompanyName': txtCompanyName,
            'txtCompanyContactPerson': txtCompanyContactPerson,

            'txtCompanyPhone': txtCompanyPhone,
            'txtCompanyFax': txtCompanyFax,

            'txtCompanyEmail': txtCompanyEmail,
            'txtCompanyWebsite': txtCompanyWebsite,

            'txtZipcode': txtZipcode,
            'txtCountry': txtCountry,

            'txtAddress1': txtAddress1,
            'txtAddress2': txtAddress2,

            'txtCompanyRegNo': txtCompanyRegNo
    },

    success: function (responceMessage) {
        alert(responceMessage);
        if (responceMessage != "1") {
            alert(responceMessage);
        } else {
            saveCompanyInformation();
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('failure');
    }

});
```

I have made sure that call is going to server side and returning proper message in string format.

But when call from `validateForm` method on server side is returned, it directly goes to failure instead of `success` method.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Console is showing:

```
GET http://localhost:49273/Company/validateForm?txtCompanyName=+x&txtCompanyCon…ebsite=&txtZipcode=&txtCountry=&txtAddress1=&txtAddress2=&txtCompanyRegNo= 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: it means you have error in server side

Comment: There is something wrong on the server side hence 500 code

Comment: But on serverside , its not showing me any exception

Comment: Is there no exceptions in server logs as well?

Answer (score 0):

I just made `cache:false` in ajax and code worked.

It was as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Company/validateForm",
            cache:false,
            dataType: "json",
            data:
                {
                    'txtCompanyName': txtCompanyName,
                    'txtCompanyContactPerson': txtCompanyContactPerson,

                    'txtCompanyPhone': txtCompanyPhone,
                    'txtCompanyFax': txtCompanyFax,

                    'txtCompanyEmail': txtCompanyEmail,
                    'txtCompanyWebsite': txtCompanyWebsite,

                    'txtZipcode': txtZipcode,
                    'txtCountry': txtCountry,

                    'txtAddress1': txtAddress1,
                    'txtAddress2': txtAddress2,

                    'txtCompanyRegNo': txtCompanyRegNo
                }
               ,

            success: function (responceMessage) {

                if (responceMessage != "0") {
                    alert(responceMessage);
                }
                else {
                    saveCompanyInformation();
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('failure');
            }

        });
```